# Generating JSON of directory structure for consumption by Webix tree widget

Tags: javascript, python, json, webix

I'm working on a project using Webix and Python/Flask and I'm hitting a brick wall with rendering a treeview widget.  My problem is properly constructing the JSON needed by the widget.  I'm trying to generate the directory structure of a given example:

Structure:

```
.
├── dirone
│   └── file
├── dirthree
│   ├── somedir
│   │   └── anotherfile
│   └── somefile
├── dirtwo
└── somefile
```

Desired output:

```
[
    {
        "value": "dirone",
        "path": "dirone",
        "type": "folder",
        "children": [
            {
                "value": "file",
                "path": "dirone/file",
                "type": "file"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "value": "dirtwo",
        "path": "dirtwo",
        "type": "folder",
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "value": "dirthree",
        "path": "dirthree",
        "type": "folder",
        "children": [
            {
                "value": "somefile",
                "path": "dirthree/somefile",
                "type": "file"
            },
            {
                "value": "somedire",
                "path": "dirone/file",
                "type": "folder",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "value": "anotherfile",
                        "path": "dirthree/somedir/anotherfile",
                        "type": "file"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "value": "somefile",
        "path": "somefile",
        "type": "file"
    }
]
```

I've been banging my head against this for the past two hours trying to get a method that can render it.  Does any have a method that generates the structure?  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is not really a solution, but Webix widgets can be configured to use a json with different structure or, in case or tree, load plain list of data records and build a tree-structure by grouping data by some parameter

Check for example
http://docs.webix.com/samples/17_datatree/01_loading/07_load_group.html

Comment: Cool, that will come in handy.  I'm trying to move away from PyQt; still trying to get a feel for some of the js widget frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it to what I need without os.walk(), but I'm still doing it via a recursive function (boo):

```
def pathTree(path,id=0):
    id += 1
        tree = {'value': os.path.basename(path)}
        tree['path'] = path
    tree['id'] = id
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            tree['type'] = "folder"
            tree['data'] = [pathTree(os.path.join(path,x),id) for x in os.listdir(path)]
    else:
            tree['type'] = "file"
    return(tree)
```

The only thing I really want now (though not really beneficiary yet) is to have it record the level/iter depth.

Thanks for the suggestions!